# how to replace characters in MS Access file using sed

Tags: ms-access, sed

I have a string in an Access file that looks like this:

```
/bin/XXX/bla.XXX.bla
```

I want to use sed in order to replace all occurences of XXX with lets say YYY within this string. the **g** flag by itself does not work probably brcause of the fact that the sting is complex and with "/".

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: This is very basic sed. For your information, you can use any delimiter when using sed. Slash is just used by convention.

Comment: my code is:
   [ sed s/XXX/YYY/g file ]   
it just disrupt my file and I dont undestand why.

Comment: But im not replacing the "/" but just the XXX. Also, this is not a regular text file. its an access file. maybe it has something to do with it.

Comment: ok, sorry I didn't read properly. Your code should work with a normal file. I am not sure about access files.

Comment: sed won't work as you expect on an access file. Why not learn about access's version of `substr`? Good luck.

Comment: It would have been helpful to say it was an Access file! `sed` is for processing text files, you need to know what you're doing to use it on binary files. If the XXX and YYY are the same length it might work, but not if you replace XXX with Y or YYYYY

Comment: thanks @Jonathan Wakely that helped!! what should I do if the string that Im replacing with is in unknown size?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
sed 's/XXX/YYY/g'
```

`g` stands for replacing all the ocurrencies

So if you have your file myfile.txt, do this:

```
sed 's/XXX/YYY/g' myfile.txt > mynewfile.txt
```

Comment: as I said before, this does not work for me. I dont know why but the file is disrupted at every table that the sed should work on

Comment: Used on an Access mdb or accdb this could be ... interesting.

Comment: Aaah so it is in MS Access! Then my answer is not useful